# PHP Curl post a file without header

Tags: php, curl

I'm not much of a PHP person, but trying to port a cli CURL call to PHP ... originally I had:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: text/csv" -X POST --data-binary @$filepath $destination
```

I've tried to turn this into:

```
<?php
$data['Filedata'] = "@".$filepath;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $destination.'/_');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/csv"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The problem is that this results in an extra header being prepended to the destination, containing `------------------------------6614b0cf8aae
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Filedata; filename=$filepath Content-Type: application/octet-stream.`

I assumed this was because of the way I used `$data['Filedata']`, so I tried replacing the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` line with the below, but that just winds up posting the path string rather than the file itself.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "@".$filepath);
```

Anyone mind pointing out what I'm missing? Like I said, not a PHP person!

Comment: did you try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just load the file content directly and it will do. Currently you are doing key/value pared POST data which is different from your original curl commandline.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($filepath));
```