# php aws sdk cannot put using signed url

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to upload a file using a signed url but I keep getting key too long error. running this via curl on cli works fine.

```
$result = "hl7/1/2df8c3ef-8eca-4e19-aae0-41b074f37c8e.hl7?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=CREDENTIALS%2F20211206%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211206T144541Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjELX%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJGMEQCIH%2BBvsVggdM0wLpK0Kd7gGVopCVYrDNxrHoJWdJZs%2Bl7AiBwFw1i3LNWsoDsK6SZzz8%2BPdHxYh%2Bn6T4DbHt5Ya5w8Sr6AwiO%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAIaDDc4MTcyNzU3MTE3NyIMK4bkPUK4yBIM3U65Ks4DQAkLuCkrZ%2F7tcoN7ItKGxmSBM0TMYbGq7dhsS1SWSxqffm%2BOM9QzEROrQRpt%2Bm%2BUQ3R5o7vz7Y4x5lxhkvIOyzXxVUqNznCBnWEYwEdK8aLPlZLiFkh2wznL2SeTLZsYO4LD3WXoY3AiVZZYZroNkJcUicNlectdsuoFWov5DIJ7k6PyAoEaRFk00Afa9W8NX5pN4NevvgclgqpceqeLD7L%2FBHBje13F68aJ6sv%2F%2FLeWZ4pvSR5ySgWaUaQ1aHHIsNVhuuZCgqC3R8wlN2AGRQ4h5M%2Byb6Tq6pFJwgI2CeP%2BgAFmMUh0feyJDROLq88i%2BRTSIEsUlH8GQGDg%2FSwIPBlL3Fg8TxDSzL8wa8Quk2h%2BgpNalvdRmIUR6iYem4DoNUxkihU%2F77g0TEOVLIl%2Fk20freTIWSeR8ZNCmIZOhUvm9Ea7TQl88B3jWq3oVWWG3xsKkEvCZ%2FwdnQAI20fUp8EtrnODtjjNNanmgWSafHURLTAm2HjtNbnKri%2B2mQmGQoHo2s2xX%2Fi6CYuEZI5yJBYuUSFZHhSum0h%2Bja643YDOp14TmYO38xFcIThxKDqaEMBjdRo15WvVDFcXSMsUdXLElXvOPMfHBoMdT4meMMiTuI0GOqYBT%2FMubfy97zprO%2FNP8xyb2u8qfDYeO0P7xBXdNFrbfVgX%2Fdr6%2Fhh8WSEz2K9PojxLN3NLGnfiMaUaUpev2kHcThP%2BuMkb%2FurH9Pl9QCFKsgKnhylrIKC0bQ%2B4TaEbJoRwh%2BRQUZGqaJfaPrMR5tAyYZ5kN4w1PXLRjpqi2U27B3qpGfu3jruEtOsuHtxM57tFQgyUHy3J%2FOdV7YVzYX%2B8cHSHkx2ndA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Signature=e653b4bbc96cba74979a087b3bc0f14ea6ff9fcd8eff0bd28234d897833240d1&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=PutObject";

$client = new S3Client( [
                            'version' => '2006-03-01',
                            'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
                            'validate' => false
                        
                        ] );
$params = [
    'Bucket' => env('RESULTS_UPLOAD_SERVICE_BUCKET'),
    'Key'    => $result,
    'Body'   => file_get_contents($fileData)
];

$response = $client->putObject($params);
```

Here is my curl command which works

```
curl --request PUT --upload-file 20211008192601_60461040005062.HL7 "https://domain.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hl7/1/2df8c3ef-8eca-4e19-aae0-41b074f37c8e.hl7?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA3MAUYDTUUN444IX6%2F20211206%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211206T144541Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjELX%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJGMEQCIH%2BBvsVggdM0wLpK0Kd7gGVopCVYrDNxrHoJWdJZs%2Bl7AiBwFw1i3LNWsoDsK6SZzz8%2BPdHxYh%2Bn6T4DbHt5Ya5w8Sr6AwiO%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAIaDDc4MTcyNzU3MTE3NyIMK4bkPUK4yBIM3U65Ks4DQAkLuCkrZ%2F7tcoN7ItKGxmSBM0TMYbGq7dhsS1SWSxqffm%2BOM9QzEROrQRpt%2Bm%2BUQ3R5o7vz7Y4x5lxhkvIOyzXxVUqNznCBnWEYwEdK8aLPlZLiFkh2wznL2SeTLZsYO4LD3WXoY3AiVZZYZroNkJcUicNlectdsuoFWov5DIJ7k6PyAoEaRFk00Afa9W8NX5pN4NevvgclgqpceqeLD7L%2FBHBje13F68aJ6sv%2F%2FLeWZ4pvSR5ySgWaUaQ1aHHIsNVhuuZCgqC3R8wlN2AGRQ4h5M%2Byb6Tq6pFJwgI2CeP%2BgAFmMUh0feyJDROLq88i%2BRTSIEsUlH8GQGDg%2FSwIPBlL3Fg8TxDSzL8wa8Quk2h%2BgpNalvdRmIUR6iYem4DoNUxkihU%2F77g0TEOVLIl%2Fk20freTIWSeR8ZNCmIZOhUvm9Ea7TQl88B3jWq3oVWWG3xsKkEvCZ%2FwdnQAI20fUp8EtrnODtjjNNanmgWSafHURLTAm2HjtNbnKri%2B2mQmGQoHo2s2xX%2Fi6CYuEZI5yJBYuUSFZHhSum0h%2Bja643YDOp14TmYO38xFcIThxKDqaEMBjdRo15WvVDFcXSMsUdXLElXvOPMfHBoMdT4meMMiTuI0GOqYBT%2FMubfy97zprO%2FNP8xyb2u8qfDYeO0P7xBXdNFrbfVgX%2Fdr6%2Fhh8WSEz2K9PojxLN3NLGnfiMaUaUpev2kHcThP%2BuMkb%2FurH9Pl9QCFKsgKnhylrIKC0bQ%2B4TaEbJoRwh%2BRQUZGqaJfaPrMR5tAyYZ5kN4w1PXLRjpqi2U27B3qpGfu3jruEtOsuHtxM57tFQgyUHy3J%2FOdV7YVzYX%2B8cHSHkx2ndA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Signature=e653b4bbc96cba74979a087b3bc0f14ea6ff9fcd8eff0bd28234d897833240d1&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=PutObject"
```

it errors with

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Error><Code>KeyTooLongError</Code><Message>Your key is too long</Message><Size>1 (truncated...)
 at /var/www/snapshot/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113)
[stacktrace]
```

Comment: Can you check what your $result value is.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving that error because you are passing pre-signed url result in to put request as key, That put request method should actually be used to upload directly with php sdk.

It seems like you want to upload file to a pre-signed url, Once you generate pre-signed url you will need to do a HTTP PUT request, you can do it directly from browser that is the usual way why we generate pre-signed url that expires  after certain time so you don't expose your keys to public.

If you are using PHP directly you could simply use your keys to upload using above code or if you still want to upload to a pre-signed url with php see this link
[How do I upload a file to an AWS Presigned URL with PHP Curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633032/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-an-aws-presigned-url-with-php-curl)